# Using build time generated, self-signed certs for inter application authentication

Tags: certificates

I need to be able to authenticate requests between different applications I am responsible for.

My company does have CA signed certs, but there are two problem with using it for this purpose. Currently, all applications share the same cert, but I do not want applications to be allowed to impersonate each other since they will have different privileges, and I want to operate under the assumption that any one application may be compromised (and that compromise should have minimum impact to other systems).

Now I realize that I could use my companies root cert to sign individual certs for all my different applications, however, the problem is, that cert is managed by another department. This other department managing the certs is very overloaded, and relying on them to sign my certs would introduce unacceptable delays in our productivity (especially given we are trying to fully automate our deployments).

My idea to get around all this is, when an application is deployed, a self-signed cert will be generated, with the public portion being placed in an internet facing location, and the private portion placed on a non-accessible portion of the server. This build generated cert would not be used for https, only signing and verification.

When one of my applications wants to authenticate a request from another, it would download the public portion of self-signed cert over https (using the regular CA secure cert) and then use it to verify the signature attached to the request.

Are there any security flaws with this approach which would make it a poor choice?

Comment: Ask the Certificate Management Department to create an Code Signing Certificate for you, so you can sign your applications' certificates.

Comment: @ThoriumBR that might have a turn around time of 2weeks of a month ;)

Comment: Only the first time... Then you have your own certificate-signing certificate...